# Where I can place the logic that generate a pdf response on my laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Ι am maintinaning a legacy laravel 5.2 application and I have the following controller:

```
namespace App\Controllers

use App\Model\MyModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController extends Controller
{
  public function myPdf(Request $request)
  {
    $filterVal = $request->get('filter_var');
    $data = MyModel::where('value',$filterVar)->get();

    // Generate a pdf response here
  }
}
```

But for me from an architectural point of view seems wrong to place any view-generation logic towards to a controller. The controller responds with a PDF response (the http response has Content Type header `application/pdf`) and having the logic in the controller is wrong because the pdf is the view of my data.

So do you have any idea how I can create custom responses that generate pdf using libraries such as DomPdf?

Comment: so basic need is to get a function which would return pdf as response?

Comment: Even better a way to make PDf responses in a simmilar approach I use .blade templates. I mean I need a way to generate custom pdf responses and be able to reuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Α quick and easy way is to make a custom class extending the Laravel's response class:

In my case  needed to render a Pdf from a blade template and in my case PDf responses will always be a 200 OK one.

```
namespace App\Http\Responses;

use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

class PdfResponse extends Response
{
  public function __construst(string $template, array $params)
  {
     parent::__construct();
     
      $htmlContent = view($template,$parameters)->render();
       
      // Replace the following lines with aany other library that converts html -> pdf 
      $dompdf = new Dompdf();
      $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
      $dompdf->loadHtml($htmlContent);
      $dompdf->render();
      
        
      $this->setStatusCode(200);
      
      // Always return application/pdf to indicate that content is PDf
      $this->header('Content-Type','application/pdf');
      $this->setContent($dompdf->output());
  }

}
```

Also instead of DOMPdf you can use any other library such as [MPdf](https://mpdf.github.io/) (a pretty interesting specimen).